# Issue with XElement ReplaceAll function

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using XElement's `ReplaceAll` function. I have the following image element which i have to replace :

```
<image x="773.35399" y="1175.40315" .... />
```

When i replace the above element with the following element :

```
<image x="23" y="11" .../>
```

an extra element is created after the call to ReplaceAll function and the replaced element is wrapped inside it. Means the above replacement result will be :

```
  <image>
    <image x="23" y="11" .../>
  </image>
```

I don't want to wrapped replaced element inside an extra element. How can i stop this behavior ?

Comment: Your question is missing sample code - you are probably calling it on wrong element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ReplaceWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx) method instead of [`ReplaceAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352767.aspx). Latter one replaces child nodes and the attributes of element, instead of replacing element itself.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
xdoc.Root.Element("image")
         .ReplaceWith(new XElement("image", 
              new XAttribute("x", 23),
              new XAttribute("y", 11)));

xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likley you are calling [ReplaceAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replaceall.aspx) on "image" node itself - which will replace all its children nodes with new content. In your case "replace children nodes" (which it did not have before the call) will simply add new "image" node as child exactly as you see.

You probably want [XElement.ReplaceWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx) instead.